# Grails relationship involving mutliple tables, possible many to many

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship, tag-cloud

The problem lies with linking a `Event Instance` to a `Tag Instance`. Upon **Saving** an event which has ***now been achieved*** ...but with design problems remaining, as one tag can be related to multiple events, and one event can have 0 to many tags.

In the standard `save()` method, I call within a method `tagInput()`, which takes the string from the form `tagsCollection field` (*see screenshots*) which separates the words and **creates/saves** an instance of the `Tag` (*see method below*). Each separated value is linked to the logged in user and now to the event the event.

The overall issue is how can I add **more than one** event instance id to each of the tags created, so that the event_id in Tag database is not overwritten with a newer event using the same tag name.

[Demo of multiple tags separated via comma](http://d.pr/i/uEWu) & [Result of tags on webpage](http://d.pr/i/q73K) & [Database: dbconsole](http://d.pr/i/uwMY)

**User Class** (*Used with Grails Security Plugin*)

```
static hasMany = [tags : Tag]
```

**Tag Class** (*for use with Tag Cloud Grails Plugin*)

```
String tag
int times
User user
// Think this needs changing to hasMany i.e. many tags, many events linked to a tag
static belongsTo = [event: Event]
```

**Event Class**

```
String tagsCollection
User user
static hasMany = [tags: Tag]
```

.

So now an **event id** is being saved to a **Tag instance** but is problematic with re-using the same tag for the same user, as it needs to have the possibility of having **multiple related event id's** for searching abilities.

```
def tagInput(Event e) {
    //Stores tags sperated via comma in an array from the eventInstance tagCollection string field
    def tagArray = e.tagsCollection.replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase().split(",")

    tagArray.each { aVar ->
        def splitTag = Tag.findByTag(aVar)
        //If the tag already exists for the current user logged in
        if (Tag.findByTag(aVar) && splitTag.userId == lookupPerson().id) {
        //Lookup person spring security method
        //+1 to how many times that tag has been used
            splitTag.times++

            //TODO IMPLEMENT A WAY TO APPEND EVENT ID TO TAG EVENT_ID FIELD

            splitTag.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        }  else {
            //if tag doesn't exist, create a new one using current logged in user
            def nTag = new Tag(tag:aVar, times: 1, user:lookupPerson())
           //SUGGESTION to save event id to a tag
            e.addToTags(nTag)
            e.save()
            //Set a user to own this tag
            def u = User.find(lookupPerson())
            nTag.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
            u.addToTags(nTag)
            u.save()
        }
    }
}
```

(To test I used *one user*, with the *first event* who *created 5 tags* **SEE DATABASE SCREENSHOT**, then *created a second event* with the *same user*, and used *two tags previously created* in the last event *t1* & *t5* )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[So you are creating an event, and you may need to create new tags along with it.

So in order for you save to cascade to the tag as well, you have to define a belongTo on the tag class:

```
class Tag {
...
static belongsTo = [Event, User]
}
```

Now you can say:

```
Event event = new Event(...)
event.addToTags( new tag(...) )
```

And `event.save()` should also save your new tag.

Edit: Your `new Tag` should probably be something like `Tag.findOrCreateByUserAndTag(user, name)`. This will find the tag if it already exists, and if it doesn't it will create it. Obviously replace the user and name variables with what you are working with.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have managed to do it with a mixture of your help and @Jinzhao Wu 

I changed the `belongsTo` to like you said for `event`

So when I call `tagInput(eventInstance)` within the `save()`. I added `eventInstance.addToTags(Tag Instance)` and then `eventInstance.save()`

Comment: I believe the problem is I'm looking at the design wrong... it's going to have to be a many to many i.e. Tag hasMany Events and Events hasMany Tags ....

Comment: Any hints or Tips on dealing with Many to Many relationships?  I am not confident on how to navigate the workings of this... the grails docs for this aren't the best in my opinion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`how can I add an event instance id to each of the tags created, when the id hasn't been created yet ...`

You can't, and you don't need to do it either. By definition Tag instances does not require an Event instance reference because there is no Event property contained in the domain class.

So you can just create the tag instances and save it without a event instance persisted: simply return the saved tagInstances list from `tagInput()` method. Back in save() method, after you save eventInstance, add the tag list to it with something like this:

```
tagInstancesList.each{tagInstance->
    eventInstance.addToTags(tagInstance)
}
```

Comment: This is partially incorrect. The tag does not require an event, however you can enable the cascading saves.

Comment: What is the benefit to enable cascade in this case? I don't understand.

Comment: So you don't have to validate the objects seperately

Comment: That's not a concern of OP.

Comment: Thank you both @JamesKleeh & @Jinzhao Wu for replying... this issue however isn't solved for me and I didn't realise my problem until fixing this stupidly :/.

It's now saving an `event instance id` to tags thanks to the both of you :) .... but, an example use case:

A user creates another event and wants to use the same tag, is there a means of adding multiple id's to the tags belongTo

I'll update my code with the `tagInput()` 

Thanks